# Batch if form with ( do ( in it?

Tags: batch-file

What I'm basically trying to do is make 2 IF's wich could then resolve in 4 do's with action in. I'm guessing i'm doing something I may not, because i get an error:

```
) was not expected
```

Could anyone enlighten me on the form I need to use for implementing the DO in a result of the IF test? Thanks a lot.

Underneath you find the code i tried to run. (it's abstraction i.o code language)

```
if (logicaltest1) ( do (
if (logicaltest2) ( do (
action 1
echo something 1
)
) else ( do (
action 2
echo something 2
)
) else (
if (logicaltest) ( do (
action 3
echo something 3
)
)
) else ( do (
action 4
echo something 4
)
)
```

The four possibility's, in booleans for the 2 if's, just so i make myself clear: `#t#t,#t#f,#f#t,#f#f`
(batch in dos)

Comment: Is this DOS batch, or something else?

Comment: As you can see at the bottom of my question i letteraly said:
(batch in dos)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Identing is the best way to find out what's wrong:

```
if (logicaltest1) (
    do (
        if (logicaltest2) (
            do (
                action 1
                echo something 1
            )
        ) else (
            do (
                action 2
                echo something 2
            )
        *)* (missing)
    *)* (missing)
) else (
    if (logicaltest) (
        do (
            action 3
            echo something 3
        )
    *)* (unexpected)
    ) else (
        do (
            action 4
            echo something 4
        )
    )
*)* (missing)
```

This should work.

Answer (score 5):

In "DOS batch", "DO" is not used in "IF" statements, but rather is attached with "FOR".

On Windows 2000/XP/Vista/7, You may type `IF /?` for help. Similarly `FOR /?` would give you help on "FOR" statement.

Sample sketch:

```
if CONDITION1 (
  if CONDITION2 (
    echo CONDITION1 true, and CONDITION2 true
  ) else (
    echo CONDITION1 true, and CONDITION2 false
  )
) else (
  if CONDITION3 (
    echo CONDITION1 false, and CONDITION3 true
  ) else (
    echo CONDITION1 false, and CONDITION3 false
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason I don't like nested IFs in batch files. When possible, I try to convert them so I always have only one level of indenting.

In case there are people who share such a disfavour, here's what could probably be done in this particular case:

```
set selector=0
if CONDITION1 set /A selector+=1
if CONDITION2 set /A selector+=2

rem Now we have only 4 possible cases for selector, from 0 to 3

if %selector% = 0 (
  ...
) else if %selector% = 1 (
  ...
) etc.
```

Of course nesting can give an advantage such that, when we have to execute some commands that only depend on `CONDITION1`, we do not have to repeat them, whereas with my approach it seems like we do. Still, I try to sort through such cases too, like using additional IFs like `if /I selector lss 2 ...` or something to that effect.